# Parameter based redirect in nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, lua, proxypass

I have http requests such as the one below being sent to an nginx server:

```
GET /app/handler?id=1234&param1=cbd&param2=234
```

Now, I want to rewrite the request to a different handler depending on the id param in the request. eg. redirect to handler_even for even ids and handler_odd for odd ids. This is shown below:

```
GET /app/handler?id=1234&param1=cbd&param2=234 => /app/handler_even?id=1234&param1=cbd&param2=234
GET /app/handler?id=123&param1=cbd&param2=234 => /app/handler_odd?id=123&param1=cbd&param2=234
```

I can do the rewrite using proxy_pass, but I'm unsure how to redirect using the id parameter value. Any idea how I could go about this? Would using "if" be the best way to go about this?

Any pointers would be useful

Comment: Redirect or rewrite?

Comment: Rewrite. Changed the question to reflect that. The end user never knows which handler he/she has been redirected to.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use an `if` directive, you could use a `map`. To internally rewrite the URI use:

```
map $arg_id $handler {
    default /app/handler_even;
    ~[13579]$ /app/handler_odd;
}

server {
    ...
    location = /app/handler {
        rewrite ^ $handler last;
    }
    ...
}
```

The `map` should be located at the same level as your `server` directive (as shown above), i.e. within the `http` container.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.